Were there consequences for the reviewers or editors of Andrew Wakefield's MMR/Autism paper?
Did the reviewers of Andrew Wakefield's MMR/Autism paper suffer any consequences (for not being thorough enough)?  What about the editor(s) of the Lancet?

I recommend that you assume the audience is not familiar with this case and provide the summary and a link.

In the meantime https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancet_MMR_autism_fraud.

What sort of ‘consequences’ should there be. They acted as if the paper was in good faith, as they should. It wasn’t.

Is it clear that the reviewers weren't thorough? Supposedly, "The Lancet's peer reviewers had raised concerns about the study's methods and interpretations, as well as about the dangers of undermining public confidence in immunisations. Dr Horton insisted that the paper was revised to clarify that its authors had no proof that MMR caused autism, following which it was published under the label of ‘early report’ to ‘highlight its preliminary nature’ "

Here is the original paper https://www.thelancet.com/action/showPdf?pii=S0140-6736%2897%2911096-0

What kind of "consequences" could even be possible for the reviewers, given that they are anonymous volunteers?  The journal has no power to fire them or cut their funding, nor could it publicly shame them without violating confidentiality.  The journal could decide not to invite them to review in the future, but I am not sure what you imagine could be done beyond that.

@JonCuster I don't know, not being in academia.  Shame, maybe? Anyon says the peer reviewers "raised concerns about hte study's methods and interpretations".  That satisfies me.

This article https://web.archive.org/web/20210624033729/https://www.spectator.co.uk/article/how-the-lancet-lost-our-trust describes several other incidents that harm the journal's credibility.

To be honest, if reviewers be made responsible for fraud or negligence by the authors of a paper, that's enough reason not to agree to ever review again. Not being paid, spending possibly days on someone else's work with likely no relevance for oneself, and then being punished if there turns out to be some major issue with the authors? Life's too short for that. Short of collusion of reviewers with the author, their work should be considered in good faith. As is the core assumption about scientific authors. If you expect people to do forensic-level investigation on any random paper, pay up.

Whenever something bad happens in peer review, it's the editors that take the heat, not the reviewers. Why? Because usually the reviewers are anonymous. Granted every now and then a reviewer is willing to identify themselves, but it takes a gutsy reviewer to say yes I reviewed this paper when the blowback is very public.
As for the editors, they definitely came under fire, but as far as I can tell nobody accused them of negligence. That's because peer review is not supposed to catch fraud. You can't send someone to the author's lab to verify that they actually conducted the research they said they did. The Lancet editor-in-chief said as much when retracting the article:

Wakefield "was dishonest", said Horton. "He deceived the journal." The Lancet had done what it could to establish that the research was valid, by having it peer-reviewed. But there is a limit, he said, to what peer-review can ascertain.
"Peer review is the best system we have got for checking accuracy and acceptability of work, but unless we went into the lab or examined every case record, we can't ever finally rule out some element of misconduct. The entire system depends upon trust. Most of the time we think it works well, but there will be a few instances – and when they happen they are huge instances – where the whole thing falls apart."

For what it's worth, The Lancet remains one of the most prestigious journals in the whole of science, so there is no lasting damage.

We should remember that Lancet did not just ignore the allegations for 12 years before retracting in 2010. For example, here is a 2004 paper, discussing various allegations, and allowing the authors to respond to them. https://www.thelancet.com/pb-assets/Lancet/extras/statement20Feb2004web.pdf

Worth noting, this isn’t just saying “peer-review carries no responsibility”.  Some kinds of problems should certainly be caught, and it’s a serious lapse of judgement if a referee and editor let them through — though as noted in the first paragraph, it’s only editors who can be held accountable.  But the problems in this specific study (primarily conflict of interest and very cherry-picked data) are not the sort that peer-review is necessarily expected to catch — they’re not apparent in the text of the paper alone, only with extra context, some requiring investigative journalism to uncover.

Accountable to whom, though? Peer review exists because there is no higher authority to appeal to that would be able to judge the subject matter.
